# s3 check if file exist by getting metadata

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to check if file exists in `s3` bucket using `AWS javascript sdk`. 
I have defined my policy to Allow `HeadBucket` for my s3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:HeadBucket",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have attached the above policy to a user and I am using that user in setting up the config for the `s3` as follows:

**aws-config.json**

```
{
    "user1": {
        "bucket": "my-bucket",
        "region": "us-east-2",
        "accessKey": "********",
        "secretKey": "*********"
    }
}
```

In my `node.js` code, I am trying to use `headObject` to get the meta data for the object as follows:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3Config = require("../data/aws-config.json").user1;
AWS.config.update(s3Config); 
var s3 = new AWS.S3;

var params = {
    Bucket: "my-bucket",
    Key: "mykey.PNG"
};
s3.headObject(params, function (err, metadata) {
    console.log(err);   
});
```

This is giving me `403 Forbidden` error. I have tried everything from changing AWS policy to allow all `s3` operations to allow access to all resources, nothing seems to work.

**EDIT**:

I checked the `AWS.config.credentials` and it is loading some random accessKey and secretKey and not from my config file. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `HEAD` object. There's no `HEAD` bucket operation which is what your IAM policy grants.

To do `HEAD` operation on an object, you need `s3:GetObject` permission.

See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) for more information.